I am getting an error while running my spark job in apache airflow
I am running this job in apache airflow
my code:
package ScalaWIthAirflow


import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
object Airflow extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Airflow")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  val df1 = spark.read
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .json("src/main/resources/cars.json")

  df1.select(
    col("Name").as("carName"),
    col("Horsepower").as("HP")
  ).show()

}

and my dag file is:
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator, BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.providers.apache.spark.operators.spark_submit import SparkSubmitOperator


dag = DAG(dag_id = "my_dag", 
    start_date=datetime(2024, 8 ,8), 
    schedule='@daily', 
    catchup=False
)
sparkJarPath = "/home/omarsobhy/IdeaProjects/ScalaWithAirflow/target/scala-2.12/scalawithairflow_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"


submit_job = SparkSubmitOperator(
    application=sparkJarPath,
        task_id="submit_job",
        conn_id ="spark_conn",
        dag=dag
        )
                        
submit_job

and the the error i am getting is:
'Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/home/omarsobhy/src/main/resources/cars.json'
When i put the file in
"home/omarsobhy/" directly or inside apache airflow home directory it works but when i put it otherwise it doesn't
I just want to know is there a parameter or a config file that i should be modifying in order to get it to work wherever my file is ?
Because i checked and the file path actually exists and the program runs correctly locally
I expect that the job in apache airflow to run successfully
